How can I add interactive Html Tags like Button, Input feild inside the Ckeditor5 Content in Angular 17
I have a custom PlugIn that adds a button to the tool bar and on the click of that I want to add a button in my ckeditor5 Content, that on clicking will give me an alert.
I tried creating the element of button, but it get sanitized, I have tried using General HTML support to avoid sanitization, but the button comes in the span of General Html Support and is for preview only, I am working in angular 17. Help is appreicated!
Here is my Custom PlugIn
editor.ui.componentFactory.add("dropdownButton", (locale) => {
  const view = new ButtonView(locale);

  view.set({
    label: "Click me",
    tooltip: true,
    class: "custom-button", // Assigning class custom-button to the button
  });

  // Handle click event
  view.on("execute", () => {
    const buttonHtml = '<button class="responsive-button">Test</button>';
    const button = new ButtonView();
    button.set({
      label: "Test",
      tooltip: true,
      class: "responsive-button",
    });

    //Insert HTML directly into the editor
    editor.model.change((writer) => {
      const viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView(buttonHtml);
      const modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);

      // Insert the button at the current selection position
      editor.model.insertContent(
        modelFragment,
        editor.model.document.selection
      );
    });
  });

  return view;
});


